# Side mouse buttons doesn't work

Tags: mouse, pop-os, events

I switched to Pop! OS, but side mouse buttons doesn't work.

On windows they were button 4 & 5, but here I used `xev` and it turns out button 4 & 5 were assigned to the scroll wheel. When I clicked side buttons it didn't say anything and didn't register it.

My mouse is TUF GAMING M5. How can I enable the side buttons?

Comment: you presented one long string of words ... please format your post into sentences

Comment: Also, please edit your question to add the make and model of your mouse, its connection type (PS/2 or USB) and if you have KVM switches or anything similar in between the computer and the mouse.